# Monotonic Sequence Probability - Combinatorics

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have my final in an hour and I studied everything else but completely forgot about this question because I didn't write it down in my notes, but just took a picture on my phone. But I need to know it for the test if anyone could please help!!

There are a bunch of strictly monotonically increasing sequences of length 17 with terms taken from the set {0,1,2,...,1000}.

1. How many possibilities are there?
          My answer would be 117C17 but I think that's monotonic not strictly monotonic?
2. If one of the sequences if chosen at random what is the probability that it will include the number 50
          My friend says it's 17/101 but cannot explain why
3. What is the probability that the median of the random sequence is equal to the median of {0,1,2,..,100}?

Sorry this is such a stupid question but I'm in a rush and I know this is my fault

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than thinking of taking a monotonically increasing sequence, we can instead consider subsets of $\{0,1,2,\ldots,1000\}$ with $17$ elements. Each of these can be uniquely rearranged to give a strictly increasing sequence, and vice versa.

Thus there are $\binom{1001}{17}$ for the first part, the chance of a $50$ occurring is $\frac{17}{1001}$ indeed.

For the third part, note that the median of $0-100$ is $50$ so really we're asking what the chance is that there are $8$ elements below $50$ and $8$ above. This chance is just $$\frac{\binom{50}{8}\binom{950}{8}}{\binom{1001}{17}}$$

Comment: thank you :)

So why is 1001 C 17 for strictly monotonic? It seems like it would include all the repeated numbers like 0,0,1,1,1,2... which is only monotonic?

Comment: essentially, you're choosing 17 elements from 0,1,2,...,1001. By definition, this doesn't let you choose the same thing twice

Comment: everything makes sense now thank you very much! :)